# See if a mysql request is Null, Empty set or has something in it

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js

I would like to know how I can get a conidition using node JS where the mysql Select request is NULL, Empty set or has something in it.

For the moment I have :

```
function checkKey(key, cb) {
    var activated = "";
    var sqlcheck = "SELECT activated from authentification where discord_key = ?";
    console.log("in function");
    DB.query(sqlcheck, [key], function (err, result) {
        if (err) throw (err);
        if (result[0] && result[0].activated) {
            activated = result[0].activated;
            console.log("filled key");
        } else {
            activated = false;
            console.log("empty key");
        }
        cb(activatedkey(activated));
        //return (activatedkey(activated));
    })
}
```

With this I get only Empty and Null OR something in it.
I am looking for a way to get EMPTY or NULL or something in it.

Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can put a second Row in your *authentification* Table with maximum of possible
key. So you can both rows with an OR, order it by key an limit it by 1.

```
SELECT activated
FROM authentification
WHERE discord_key = 123456
OR discord_key = 9999999
ORDER BY discord_key LIMIT 1;
```

**Sample**

```
    MariaDB [test_arduino]> SELECT * FROM authentification;
    +----+-----------+-------------+
    | id | activated | discord_key |
    +----+-----------+-------------+
    |  1 | 1         | 12345       |
    |  2 | EMPTY     | 9999999     |
    +----+-----------+-------------+
    2 rows in set (0.001 sec)

MariaDB []> SELECT activated
        ->     FROM authentification
        ->     WHERE discord_key = 12345
        ->     OR discord_key = 9999999
        ->     ORDER BY discord_key LIMIT 1;
    +-----------+
    | activated |
    +-----------+
    | 1         |
    +-----------+
    1 row in set (0.001 sec)

    MariaDB []> SELECT activated
        ->     FROM authentification
        ->     WHERE discord_key = 123456
        ->     OR discord_key = 9999999
        ->     ORDER BY discord_key LIMIT 1;
    +-----------+
    | activated |
    +-----------+
    | EMPTY     |
    +-----------+
    1 row in set (0.001 sec)

    MariaDB []>
```